# 2014 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

English Language & Usage's [3rd moderator election](https://english.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: Andrew Leach] [image: Yoichi Oishi] [image: Matt]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://english.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6472855084597248/0).

Comment: Congratulations winners!

Comment: Add mine to @phenry's. Congrats!

Comment: @phenry: I'm interested to see how close things got by the final rounds of vote transfer. Particularly since if I *could* have cast four votes, they would have been for you and the eventual three winners. I know you were ambivalent about the whole thing, but my congratulations and thanks to you and all the others who stood, win or lose.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I finished fourth in the final (8th) round with 137.986106 votes, behind Matt with 144.413502 votes. I was in 3rd place until the 6th round, when Matt got the bulk of the votes that were transferred after Oishi-san passed the threshold. Thanks for your kind words--this has been quite an experience, and I wish the winners well!

Comment: @phenry: I won't deny that I thought "objectively" speaking you could probably discharge the duties of a mod better than Yoichi, but I just couldn't resist the chance to vote for our favourite "grandfather of the house". :) In all seriousness though, I did and do genuinely respect your decision to stand despite initial reluctance. I'm afraid I would never manage that myself.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I will never criticize someone for voting for Oishi-san.

Comment: "Can you feel the love tonight?"  Yes, that was a great race!  I know I voted for two of the winners, Yoichi and Andrew, but I honestly can't remember my other vote.  Is there a way to look back and see one's own votes?

Answer (score 25):

Thanks a lot to Shog9 and Robusto-san, and many of my Senpais and friends who voted for me on this election. To be honest, I didn’t fancy I can win. However, my motivation for candidacy this time was to encourage non-native English speaking users in this site and many of English enthusiast friends around me by challenging this unique opportunity, and by proving that even a non-native English learner who’s never lived in English-speaking countries, no matter how he is old, can get a fair opportunity and place for giving a say about the improvement and advancement of the site abreast with native speaking Senpais and colleagues. 
I’m sure my peers in local English learning circles would join me in aknowledging my fortunate election result. Again many thanks for your support and continued assistance in improving English language proficiency.

Comment: おめでとうございます。亀の甲より年の功。

Comment: 年の功よりRobusto-sanのお陰

Comment: Yes Oishi-san! おめでとうございます。Very happy that you have been chosen by the community as a Moderator.  Your questions are always among my favorites!  Ganbatte!

Comment: @marc cenedella. Thank you very much for your  おめでとうございます. I'll try as much I can. But I'm afraid if the Mod's name bounds me to think twice whether the question deserves the name of Mod'one before posting a question. But I decided to take the freedom of asking question regardless wehther it looks good or silly to our peers.

Comment: Congratulations!

Answer (score 11):

Congrats to all y'all! . . . . . .

Comment: And to y'allselves, youse guyz, youzuns, youuns, allyous, and all and sundry. But not yinz. Never yinz.

Comment: @choster yinz got a problem wif Pittsburgh?

Answer (score 7):

Best of luck to our new and continuing moderators. You are a thoughtful and judicious group, and I'm confident that all of you will do fine work for EL&U.

To the nonwinning candidates, I just want to say thanks for running, and please stay as active and engaged in the site as you've been in the past. Two of you were my top two choices, and I know that you would have done a great job as well.

I enjoy this site immensely, but I think that it has room for improvement, most notably in encouraging newer users to ask and answer legitimate questions. One way to help make that happen is to recognize promising questions and answers with upvotes—and I plan to be less parsimonious in that regard than I've been in the past, especially in responding to users for whom an upvote can be quite encouraging and a downvote quite discouraging.

Ultimately our shared goal is a site full of good questions and good answers, not victory in a never-ending race for points.

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations and best of luck to our three new moderators. My simpathy to those who weren't elected but, I'm sure, love EL&U and will continue to give their much needed contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Right mods!! Exactly as I voted!! Congratulations!! Moderate!!

Comment: Almost exactly as I voted and I am sure that the mechanism produced a better outcome than if we'd just allowed me to appoint them.  :)

Comment: I don't know who down-voted nicael's post and why down-voted while all others saying the same thing - congratulations.

Comment: Congrats, @YoichiOishi ♦ ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**We wuz robbed!**

As your first task, should you choose to accept it, you will monitor, comment upon, edit as necessary, close, should it be required, all responses as to the etymology of this exclamatory phrase (as well as decide as to the appropriateness of follow-on questions as to its relative regional and national usage).

Answer (score 1):

Congratulation winners!!. I hope that you'd bring more enthusiasm to this group by providing your valuable knowledge to English learners. Please make this site more interactive and well discipline by taking pragmatic measures.

All the very best for your future endeavors.

Answer (score 1):

Congrats new mods.  I am not sure who I even voted for but thought everyone would do a good job.  [I was on a beach fully under the influence with the sun glaring on an Ipad and the interface for SE isn't the best sometimes let alone my choppy connection with the island's wifi]

But I think I voted for phenry because he is militant.  Stay thirsty!